# Analysis question limit $\lim_{n \to \infty} (-1)^n$

Tags: real-analysis, limits-without-lhopital, indeterminate-forms

Can someone please explain to me how we should evaluate this limit, I just know that it's indeterminate form and I tried to use L'Hospital's rule but I couldn't do it here what I have done
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} (-1)^n$$
$$=e^{n\ln(-1)}$$
But $\ln$ of $-1$ doesn't exist because the domain issue of $\ln$.

Comment: $((-1)^n)$ is an oscillating sequence, it doesn't converge.

Comment: Moreover, you can't apply L'Hospital rule (which refers to function) to sequence.

Comment: Is it always true that $a^b = \mathrm e^{b \ln a} $ ?

Comment: @Sewer Keeper I think as long as "a" is positive the equality holds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since$$(-1)^n=\begin{cases}-1&\text{ if $n$ is odd}\\1&\text{ if $n$ is even,}\end{cases}$$your sequence has a subsequence which converges to $1$ and it has a subsequence that converges to $-1$. Therefore, it diverges.

Comment: Thank you it helped me alot

Comment: I'm glad I could help.

Comment: 1_If it was -1^n * cos(n) ? could we bound them because cos (n) and -1^n both become one if we bound them and I wonder the result of lim as n -> infinity becomes 1 in this case ? 2_in general I see that sometimes we bound when we want to evaluate the limit why and when should we use this?

Comment: That's another question. I suggest that you post it as such.

Answer (score 1):

Note that, the formula $ x= e^{\ln x}$,which you applied only applies to $x>0$.
You can directly check odd and even subsequences to see where they converge. If both converge to same limit, the sequence is Convergent, otherwise not.

Comment: thank you for your answer I had one more question that is related to this; 1_If it was -1^n * cos(n) instead ? could we bound them because cos (n) and -1^n both become one if we bound them and I wonder the result of lim as n -> infinity becomes 1 in this case ? 2_in general I see that sometimes we bound when we want to evaluate the limit why and when should we use this?

Comment: $(-1)^n \cos n$ is bounded by $1$ implies $\displaystyle{\lim_{(n\to \infty) }} (-1)^n \cos n \leq 1$, if it exists. But you can show the limit does not exist similarly.

Comment: Thank you very much